# Using nestedset for site navigation

Tags: nested-sets

I would like to use a nested set to manage the navigation of a website. Would it be better to have a single page model and just make the parent names define the sections of the site or would it be better to have a category model which can be nested and a separate page model, each of which belong to a category?

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the sets in NestedSet are well suited for defining the structure of your pages (ie. building navigation and such).  If you find that you have the need to categorize your pages, you can use another NestedSet to store that structure.